# iOS - Horizontally sliding items

Tags: ios, touch, horizontal-scrolling, sliding

I have some picture, let's say like rectangular piece of paper. I want to position it on the center of the screen, and when user slides left or right with its finger (let's say left), that piece of paper should go left (with the finger), and from the right should come new piece of paper with some new information.

I hope that my description isn't confusing. I guess that this functionality should be easy to do with iOS SDK, I just don't know what to use ...

Thanks for any help ;)

Comment: How about using a standard UIScrollView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use a `UIScrollView` for that. You add your "pieces of paper" -- which I assume will be views (`UIImageView`s perhaps?) -- as subviews, and set the `contentSize` property of the scroll view to fit them all. You might also want to set the `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` property of the scroll view to `NO`, to hide the scroller.

Off the top of my head, I imagine something like this:

```
UIScrollView *aScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
aScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;

CGFloat paperWidth = 320;
NSUInteger numberOfPapers = 5;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfPapers; i++) {
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(paperWidth * i, 0, paperWidth, aScrollView.bounds.size.height)];
    imageView.image = LOAD_IMAGE_HERE...;
    [aScrollView addSubview:imageView];
}

CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(paperWidth * numberOfPapers, aScrollView.bounds.size.height);
aScrollView.contentSize = contentSize;

[self.view addSubview:aScrollView];
```

Comment: Cool, that's almost what I wanted :) Do you know how can I make it to "snap" to only one UIImageView ? I don't want it to stop and show little of two UIImageViews ... When it should stop at middle, I want it to scroll a little more until whole UIImageView is visible. If you go to AppStore on iPhone, select something and then go to the bottom of the page. There are some screen shots, and if you try to scroll between them, you'll never be stuck in middle - you will always see one screenshot. I hope you understand what I want :) Thanks again !!

Comment: @xx77aBs What you're looking for is the `pagingEnabled` property. Like this: `aScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;`.